# connection checker java class in spring boot using HikariCP

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Jboss have a mechanism where by I can execute a connection checker class([OracleValidConnectionChecker](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbzoGhupDhAhVIA2MBHRZGDcMQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jboss.org%2Fjbossas%2Fjavadoc%2F4.0.2%2Forg%2Fjboss%2Fresource%2Fadapter%2Fjdbc%2Fvendor%2FOracleValidConnectionChecker.java.html&usg=AOvVaw3HPYVVvZvRrpF3vspe7lQl)) before a connection is checked out from the connection pool. That would be helpful in calling a stored procedure before each DB call.(This is needed for setting security context in DB layer for Oracle Layer Security)

Is there any similar mechanism in spring boot (tomcat) using HikariCP ? 
I know that there is a connection checker SQL query config (spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query). But I am looking for a way to execute a Procedure with input parameters.

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1346

Answer (score -1):

As per https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby I believe `connectionInitSql` would make more sense in your case. `connectionTestQuery` is for "legacy" drivers that do not support the JDBC4 `Connection.isValid()`.

You may be able to construct your own stored procedure query and pass it into this property, however, be wary you will not benefit from the protection prepared statements generally provide eg. sql injection.

Comment: No. That's what I mentioned in my question. I know that Hikari provides way to execute a query. But I want a stored procedure that I can pass parameters as well.